# How to disable authentication for Spring Boot actuator?

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

All options I've found and tried don't work. This option in particular:

```
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      return http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize 
               .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to(HealthEndpoint.class)).permitAll()
               .anyRequest())
            .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this one approach?

```
authorize.requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll();
```

Usually actuator endpoints is exposing to `/actuator/**` but your try to give access to others endpoints path:

```
InfoEndpoint.class = /info/
HealthEndpoint.class = /health
```

The `SecurityFilterChain`  bean will look so:

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain filterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  return http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize  -> {
  authorize.requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll();
  authorize.anyRequest().authenticated();
}).build();
}
```

Comment: How does the whole bean looks like?

Comment: i updated the answer, can you check ?